# Google App Engine Datastore how to get entity for Key<?>

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm new to Datastore and now I'm developing Gae application with Datastore and Objectify. Entity class has the form

```
@Entity
public class MyClass1 {
  public Key<MyClass2> field1;
  @Id Long id;
  and so on
 }
```

MyClass2 has the form

```
@Entity
public class MyClass2 {
  ....
  @Id public Long id;
  @Index public String field2;
  ....
}
```

I have entity of MyClass1. How can I get the value of field2 ? 
If I use DatastoreService1.get(myclass1.field1) I get

```
   method get(Key) in the DatstoreService is not applicable for arguments (Key<MyClass2>)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error doesn't really relate to the question, so I assume you want to get the value of `field1`, not `field2`.

The error is because the `DatastoreService` `get()` method expects a [`com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key), but you are passing it a [`com.googlecode.objectifyKey<T>`](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.6), which is an Objectify key - they're not the same thing.  [Here are the docs](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#keys).

I would recommend using a `Ref<MyClass2>` as you can then just do something like:

```
MyClass2 myClass2 = myClass1.field1.get();
```

(using your code example).